# Why is CommonsRequestLogging ignoring logging level configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to log my application requests by using the CommonsRequestLoggingFilter, I have a @Configuration class

```java
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingConfig {

   @Bean
   public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
       CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
            = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();

       filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
       filter.setIncludePayload(true);
       filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
       filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
       filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
       return filter;
    }
}
```

The thing is, this configuration class is in my "Core" module, which I add as a dependency in my application, this core module has its own properties file, core.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

My application has its own application.properties, which doesn't include the line above, it also has a `@PropertySource("classpath:core.properties")` annotation to use the core module properties file. When I run the application, I can see the filter is configured, and if I go to my `/actuator/env` endpoint I see the property set

```
[...]
{
            "name": "class path resource [core.properties]",
            "properties": {
                "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include": {
                    "value": "*"
                },
                "spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion": {
                    "value": "non_null"
                },
                "spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion": {
                    "value": "true"
                }
            }
        }
[...]
```

But I don't get the log for the requests I make, funny enough if I put the line 
`logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG`

In the application.properties file, the log works perfectly.
My question is: what am I doing wrong? Are there any other steps I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

are you logging using a `logback.xml` file ? If then maybe you can try to update this file as well.

Did you rebuild your JAR/WAR file ? (If on intellij maybe try to launch a build to ensure everything is up to date !)

Also using actuator, you can see (and also change but here that's not the point) the logging levels. What can you see when you call the logger endpoint ?